# Mocking a file in python

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

In my python package I have a configuration module that reads a yaml file (when creating the instance) at an explicit location, i.e. something like

```
class YamlConfig(object):

    def __init__(self):

        filename = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), '.hanzo\\config.yml')

        with open(filename) as fs:
            self.cfg = yaml.load(fs.read())
```

Now what should I do when writing my unit test if I don't want to use the explicitly specified file? Instead I want to create a temporary `config.yml` to be used for testing.

I could simply allow for a specified filename in `__init__()`, but I strongly prefer forcing the filename location. I.e. like this

```
class YamlConfig(object):

    def __init__(self, filename=os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), '.hanzo\\config.yml')):

        with open(filename) as fs:
            self.cfg = yaml.load(fs.read())
```

Is there other ways to solve my issue? I guess it might be possible using `mock` right way? Also feel free to give any comments about upside and downside.

Comment: Do you need some specific content in that file or you just need a virtual temporary file?

Comment: Yes some yaml content that I specify in my unit test

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the test inside the mock context:

```
import unittest.mock as umock

with umock.patch('__main__.open', umock.mock_open(read_data='yaml data')):
    # Run your test here and open the file
    with open('filename') as f:
```

You might need to use library yaml to generate yaml output for read_data

Answer (score 0):

I did this for one of my projects. Here's what my function looked like (simplified):

```
def parse_template(cve: str) -> Dict:
"""Parse yaml templates and return relevant information

Args:
    cve: CVE id to identify respective template

Returns:
    Dict: return CVE name
"""
    year = cve.split("-")[1]
    file_path = f"/cves/{year}/{cve}.yaml"
    with open(file_path, "r") as f:
        data = yaml.load(f, Loader=yaml.SafeLoader)
    return {
        "name": data.get("name", "None")
    }
```

To write tests for this, we first create a python fixture which patches the "open" function which is responsible for opening my yaml file.

```
@pytest.fixture
def mock_template(mocker: MockFixture):
    """Mock yaml file"""

    sample_dict={
        "name":"Example cve name"
    }
    mocked_yaml = mocker.mock_open(read_data=yaml.dump(sample_dict))
    mocker.patch("builtins.open", mocked_yaml)
```

Then we just use this fixture to validate our function with something like:

```
def test_parse_template(mock_template:pytest.fixture) -> None:
"""Tests for opening yaml template and extract data"""
    result=parse_template(cve="CVE-2022-1337")
    assert "name" in result.keys() # or any other validation
```